# Sync members of a particular Azure AD group as owners to all other AD groups using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I need to sync members of a particular Azure AD group as the owner to all other AD groups using PowerShell. Currently, I understand we cannot add an AD group as the owner to other AD groups. Please help me with a workaround so that I can fetch users from an AD group and add the members of that group as owners of all other AD groups.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a design idea.

Use `Get-AzureADGroupMember -ALL 1` to get the list of all members of an Azure AD group: List 1. See [Get-AzureADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0).

Use `Get-AzureADGroup -ALL 1` to get a list of all Azure AD groups: List 2. See [Get-AzureADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0).

Exclude the particular Azure AD group from List 2： List 3.

Loop through List 1 and List 3: Add the member of List 1 as the owner to member of List 3 by using `Add-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId {objectId} -RefObjectId {refObjectId}`. See [Add-AzureADGroupOwner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureadgroupowner?view=azureadps-2.0).